# npm issue after update

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, npm-install

After update npm i cannot use `npm install` when i run

```
npm install
```

i've got

```
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module './lib/extract-stream.js'
```

The location of `extract-stream.js` is `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/extract-stream.js`

If i run

```
/usr/local/bin/npm install   # IT WORKS!
```

when i run

```
which npm 
# output: {my_home_path}/.npm-global/bin/npm
```

and when i run

```
npm -v 
# output: 6.7.0

/usr/local/bin/npm -v
# output 6.5.0
```

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Make sure you install your modules with one version of `npm`.

Comment: ran into the same issue... watching...

Comment: I had the same issue because I installed a different version of npm using brew. I uninstalled that version using 'brew uninstall npm', restarted the terminal and it went back to normal. Maybe you did the same?

Answer (score 7):

```
brew uninstall --force node    
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
brew install npm
```

Worked just fine

Comment: I would say you should prefer nvm too. so, you can manage versions and can avoid mix versioning errors. In your case, you have installed two versions of node. Try using nvm along with.

Answer (score 3):

First delete the file 'composer.lock.json' and run `rm -rf node_modules` to remove the node_modules folder. After this try to re-install npm with `npm install`.

Note: if you get this error `node_modules/.bin/npm: No such file or directory`. Run `hash -r` and after this `npm install`.